# Working with the FlowDir in the national hydography dataset

Tags: united-states, rivers, flow-direction, water, nhd

In the [National Hydrography Dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Hydrography_Dataset) there's a FlowDir field.

According to https://www.townofnewipswich.org/sites/g/files/vyhlif4766/f/uploads/dataset_dictionary.pdf the two possible values for FlowDir are 1 for "with digitized" and 0 for "uninitialized".

According to https://nhd.usgs.gov/userGuide/Robohelpfiles/NHD_User_Guide/Interactive_Tutorials/Module_2/Navigating_the_Network/Navigating_the_Network.htm "*Flow direction is from the ‘Start’ junction to the ‘End’ junction. If flow direction is incorrect,  NHDFlowline features may be ‘flipped’ to correct the flow direction.*".

The shapefile has a sequence of coordinates. Maybe the first coordinate in this sequence is the "start"?

There's also an [NHDFlowlineVAA](https://nhd.usgs.gov/userGuide/Robohelpfiles/NHD_User_Guide/Feature_Catalog/Data_Dictionary/Data_Dictionary.htm) attribute table. In this table there's fromnode and tonode columns. But...  when I try to open that file with [DBF View](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dbf-view/9pj649k2zdcq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) I get the following error:

> Exception executing: 'select * from NHDFlowlineVAA.dbf One or more errors occurred. - The provider could not determine the Decimal value. For example, the row was just created, the default for the Decimal column was not available, and the consumer had not yet set a new Decimal value.

[OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) gave me 0.00000 for both of those for everything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same situation.
To use the VAA table, you will need to download the NHDPlus HR dataset(https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHDPlusHR/Beta/GDB/), not NHD. All VAAs in NHD are empty/0.

Comment: So I just tried to download this and... using ogr2ogr to import the FileGDB stuff and the only columns I get back are: `OGR_FID`, `permanent_identifier`, `externalid, externalidname`, `externalidorginator`, `organizationtype`, `externalidentrydata`. The raster files are GeoTIFFs. If there's a way to get the VAA table from that it's unclear to me how...